# a problem , Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I know the question is not a new one , but I have tried all the solutions mentioned in other articles , which didn't work at all on my device. So I think there are something different .And here are the question and my computer configuration.

[SC] StartService: OpenService 失败 1060:

指定的服务未安装。

Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed. To install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors
Done

设备名称    LAPTOP-9D1HR6UR
处理器 AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics            3.00 GHz
机带 RAM  16.0 GB (15.4 GB 可用)
系统类型    64 位操作系统, 基于 x64 的处理器

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that issue a while ago, just to check, do you have SVM enabled on your BIOS? I had that off for me, when I enabled it I was able to install the AMD Virtualisation Driver and it worked. You can quickly check by going into System Info, looking for Hyper-V and seeing if it is marked as "Yes".

Comment: I have Intel processor and I have already enabled Virtualization technology on my BIOS. However ,it didn't work.  And I noticed that other familiar issues mentioned "[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201."But I don't have that .What does it mean?

Comment: The problem is now solved! I turned on the "虚拟机平台“（which is the Hyper-V but I didn't know ), and the problem went away. Thanks a lot!